# Getting "multiple definition of `main'" error while working with multiple C++ files in CLion

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, clion

Within my project, I made some files for different beginner programs to start coding in CLion. However, I am getting a "multiple definition of main'" error when I try to run my program. I have read that this error occurs when there are multiple definitions of the main' function in the program, but I am not sure how to resolve it. Even though I am told that I am supposed to write the main function in every program I write.

Here are the steps I am following:

1. I create a new C++ file in my project folder.
2. I write the code for the program in this file.
3. I try to run the program by clicking on the "Run" button in CLion.
4. I get the "multiple definition of `main'" error.

Code example:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}

// file2.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "This is another file.";
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
CMakeFiles/Workspace_Mashup.dir/file2.cpp.obj: In function `main':
file2.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
CMakeFiles/Workspace_Mashup.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I downloaded MinGW from GitHub and I connected the path to Clion.
Help will really be appreciated

Comment: It is not valid for a single C++ program to have multiple `main`s.  You have to tell CLion that these two `.cpp` files are not part of the same executable - e.g. by putting them in different projects or build targets.

Comment: You appear to be adding new files to the same project, and that project now has multiple `main` files (albeit in different source code `.cpp` files).  You'll need one separate project file for each project.

Comment: The fact that you are a newbie doesn't relate to the question itself. Please don't post such phrases as "I'm a beginner" for they will be considered noise. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that this is exactly what is going on, but I would guess that Clion is compiling every .cpp file in the project, whether or not it is supposed to be. This means that when the compiler finds two `main()` functions, it doesn't know what to do about it. You can either make a project for every file, or try to figure out how to make Clion only compile specific files.
It might seem like a pain now, but there is a reason that this assumption is made. When you start making very large projects it makes life easier.